# Customize vc-next-action to open a URL

Tags: version-control, svn

Is there a way to customize vc-next-action `C-x v v` so that it opens a URL on success?

I am using SVN and after each commit, I have to open manually a trac URL with the rev number. 
For example: http://server/trac/changeset/138258/project

I tried `C-u C-x v v` but without success.

Or is there an even better way to deal with SVN from Emacs?

Thanks.